# Unable to install .whl files through command prompt with pip install

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, pip, command-prompt

I am attempting to install .whl file types to Python, specifically the numpy+mkl 1.14 via the command prompt. When I put in the command `pip install "numpy-1.14.2+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"` I get the following output.

> numpy-1.14.2+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
>   this platform.

I have not found a fix that works for me and I have done the following:

- Ensure I have the correct version and file type for my version via `pip.pep425tags.get_supported()`

> Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64
>   bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> ...
>
> ('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win_amd64')

- ensured pip is up to date via `pip --version`

> pip 9.0.3 from c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

- changed the name to cp36-none-win_amd64 to attempt to work around the name

> numpy-1.14.2+mkl-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
>   this platform.

Comment: that definitely _should_ work. Well, sometimes picking the latest latest software is like being a test pilot...

Comment: any other wheel you had trouble with? or some worked?

Comment: Please show the full output of `pip --version`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had the same suspicion and tried installing the tenserflow.whl and got the same error. I have a feeling this is definitely something related to Microsoft I have had countless issues like this surrounding their stuff... I like the older version idea and will try that next.

Comment: as an alternative, there are probably anaconda packages containing all the classic math stuff you need.

Comment: @phd `pip 9.0.3 from c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: ahhh I know what the issue is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're running the *wrong* `pip` executable.

You should run Python 3.6 *64 bit*, you're running the 32 bit version. Of course, it complains because a 32 bit `pip` cannot install 64 bit packages (on the 32 bit associated version)

Locate python 64 bit (I have it in `C:\Program Files\Python36`), then in the `Scripts` subdir you have `pip`. Type full path:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip" install "numpy-1.14.2+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```

You may have to run it from an *elevated cmd* to get sufficient install rights

(phd comment helped to solve it by suggesting to try `pip --version`, kudos)

Comment: You and phd are correct. However the question then became why was I running  a 32-bit version of Python when I installed a 64-bit version? Turns out I have a copy of Visual Studio 32-bit installed with the Python package which was overriding the path of the 64-bit installation. I removed the 32-bit version and changed the path back to the 64-bit version. Now it works like a charm. Good catch!